# MockMVC test - MockBean vs Mock issue with mockito whens?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, mockmvc

I have the following mock mvc test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class PersonControllerShould {

    @MockBean
    private PersonActivity personActivity;

    @MockBean
    private PersonMapper mapper;

    @Mock
    private MongoConfig mongoconfig;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }
    
    // tests...
    
    }
```

Note that my `activity` and `mapper` classes are both spring managed `@Components.`

My MongoConfig class is as follows (not a component), hence why I have not created it as @MockBean (was giving me errors when trying this)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cosmosdb")
@ConstructorBinding
public class MongoConfig {

    // rest of code...
}
```

any `mockito` whens that I write on the `MongoConfig` do not seem to run, what is the issue here - is it possible to use both mockbeans and mocks in a mockmvc class?

Controller for reference:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonActivity personActivity;
    private final PersonMapper mapper;
    private final MongoConfig mongoconfig;

    public PersonController(
            @Autowired PersonActivity personActivity;
            @Autowired PersonMapper mapper;
            @Autowired MongoConfig mongoconfig;
    ) {

        this.personActivity = personActivity;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.mongoconfig = mongoconfig;
    }
    
        // rest mappings 

    }
```

Comment: Why should it? It isn't part of the context (whereas `@MockBean` is). BUt creating a mock of a configuration is pretty pointless as the configuration has already been processed before you have the opportunity to create a mock and replace it. So what is it you want to achieve with the mocked configuration properties? Feels like you should just add some `@TestPropertySource` instead to override some annotations.